# Jackson: getting the object on the deserializer class on the keys from a map

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization

We have the following code:

```
@JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = DomainInstanceDeserializer.class, contentUsing = FactDeserializer.class)
private final Map<DomainInstance, Fact> facts;
```

The `DomainInstanceDeserializer` has the following code in place:

```
public class DomainInstanceDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
public Object deserializeKey(String domainInstanceAsString, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) {
```

The `FactDeserialzer` has the following code in place:

```
public class FactDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Fact> {
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
    public Fact deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
        JsonNodeType nodeType = node.getNodeType();
        switch (nodeType) {
```

As it can be seen for the `Fact` we can use the object type from the node to see of which type it is.

Can this be done on the key, for the `DomainInstance`?

We use the annotation `keyUsing` which implies using the `KeyDeserializer` class. Is there another class that can be used on the key for the map?

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood your question. It doesn't seem to be possible with Jackson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Map` in `JSON` is represented as `JSON Object` which always has keys as `string` you can not expect there anything else then `String`.

You need to encode type manually. For example, you can use underscores: `type_value1_value2_value3` and decode it in `KeyDeserializer`.

Comment: So will have everytime a String there. I will do some sorting of encoding. Thank you!